# Is it possible to get the this inside an arrow function as well as the global this?

Tags: javascript, scope, this, arrow-functions

I have:

```
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
            console.log(this.checked)
        })
```

The problem is that `this.checked` is undefined because of the arrow function. So how can I check the value of the checkbox?  I know I can use a regular `function`, but I want to keep `this` to the outer scope since I will call some functions from it

Comment: Have you tried `checkbox.checked` instead of `this.checked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defeats the purpose of arrow functions. Use the event object to get the reference to the element that was clicked.

```
checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.checked)
})
```

And you also have the checkbox defined as a variable so you could use that

```
checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(checkbox.checked)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that I've done before when working with this type of scope encapsulation is to use a variable to keep "this" for reference later.

```
var me = this;
checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log(me.checked)
})
```

Using a variable like this can lead to a lot of memory usage, as you keep adding references to things that should eventually be garbage collected, so be wary of doing it too much.

And there's always the option of getting/finding the correct element for checking the status. This will likely use fewer resources in the long run and not significantly impact the speed of your app.

Even if you need to use a different context for checking the status of your checkbox/radio button, you'll at least be able to figure out what context "me" is.

Comment: `me` will be equal to `this` inside the arrow function and will not be linked to `checked` property of the input.

Comment: @epascarello, unfortunately, one of my previous jobs did this a lot. The variable "me" doesn't somehow switch the context, as you suggest, which is why they used it so much.

Comment: That would be if you want to maintain this, problem here is fat arrow is maintaining this so it is not useful here. if it were `'change', function () { console.log(me, this); }` it would make a difference